# Apache HttpResponse when sending unusual characters in body (POST verb)

Tags: http, post, serialization, apache-commons-httpclient

i got something like that :

(using : org.apache.http.HttpResponse)

```
String jsondata = "{\"issuerName\": \"Sarl.\"}";

try {
  httpPost.setHeader(getAuthorizationHeader(LOGIN_KEY));
  StringEntity jsonparam = null;
  jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata);
  jsonparam.setChunked(true);
  httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

  httpPost.setEntity(jsonparam);
  response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

  if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
  // some code
```

all is fine in this case, with the payload Sarl.
BUT, if i replace

```
String jsondata = "{\"issuerName\": \"Sarl.\"}";
```

by

```
String jsondata = "{\"issuerName\": \"Sàrl.\"}";
```

the serialization doesn't seem to be correct, as remote API never respond in 200 (it works well with Postman, with the same payload.

Does anybody has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify UTF-8 for your StringEntity, i.e.

```
jsonparam = new StringEntity(jsondata, "UTF-8");
```

You may also need to set the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header for UTF-8, i.e.

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it's working for you.